# Create a route that return list if there is no param and return a single object if there is id param

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I have one route named `/project`, I want it this way if there is no param it will return list of projects, if there is id param in url it will return a single object

Currently this is what I have

```
@GetMapping(value={"/project", "/project/"})
public List<Project> getProjects() {
    return projectService.getProjects();
}

@GetMapping("/project/{id}")
public Project getProject(@PathVariable int id) {
    Optional<Project> project = projectService.getProject(id);

    if (project.isPresent()) {
        return (Project) project.get();
    }

    return null;
}
```

`/project` will return the list

`/project/1` will return a single object

but what I wanted is

`/project` will return the list

`/project?id=1` will return a single object

how to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in other answer. you need to use [RequestParam](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/RequestParam.html). Additionally, in order to narrow down the mappings and deal with possible ambiguous handler mapping exceptions, you can use `GetMapping.params` to specify, which parameters need to be present to map to this particular handler. It's alias for [RequestMapping.params](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/RequestMapping.html#params()).

> Same format for any environment: a sequence of "myParam=myValue" style expressions, with a request only mapped if each such parameter is found to have the given value. Expressions can be negated by using the "!=" operator, as in "myParam!=myValue". "myParam" style expressions are also supported, with such parameters having to be present in the request (allowed to have any value). Finally, "!myParam" style expressions indicate that the specified parameter is not supposed to be present in the request.

Example:

```
@GetMapping(value="/project", params = "!id")
public List<Project> getProjects() {
  return projectService.getProjects();
}

@GetMapping(value = "/project", params = "id")
public Project getProject(@RequestParam int id) {
  Optional<Project> project = projectService.getProject(id);

  if (project.isPresent()) {
    return (Project) project.get();
  }
  return null;
}
```

If you consider the functional style cleaner, you can return like this:

```
return project.orElse(null);
```

Comment: Now this answer would be even better without the abuse of the optional. Just do `return project.orElseGet(() -> null)`. Or even better return `ResponseEntity<Project>` and do `return ResponseEntity.of(project);` which will return the value or a 404 if not found.

Comment: @M.Deinum I'll have to disagree about the optional abuse. If `project` was wrapped in an optional in order to hide null checks, that's certainly an abuse. But `if (Optional.isPresent()) { doSomething }` is absolutely normal usage, considering that it uses result returned from the service. I also find the functional style much cleaner when working with optionals, but that's a matter of preference and not using it is not an abuse in any way.

Comment: According to the Brian Goetz (one of the java maintainers) it is abuse of `Optional` or at least the wrong usage. He did a whole talk (multiple I guess) on the wrong patterns for optional, streams etc.

Answer (score 0):

I believe what you're looking for is the `@RequestParam` annotation. You can use it by replacing `@PathVariable` like so:

```
@GetMapping("/project")
public Project getProject(@RequestParam int id) {
    Optional<Project> project = projectService.getProject(id);

    if (project.isPresent()) {
        return (Project) project.get();
    }

    return null;
}
```

Then you can do `/project?id=1`

Note: <s>You might have to change your request url since you have two of the same mappings, but I'm not entirely sure</s> please refer to [Chaosfire's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75957375/13927534) for a solution to the ambiguous mapping problem.

Comment: when I add this, and running /project?id=1 it still called my public List<Project> getProjects() function and return a list

Comment: @NaldDev Oh actually my bad, you don't specify `{id}` in the url, will update my answer

Comment: thank You, I saw your updated answer, but this one will create a Ambiguous handler methods mapped

since the first /project is for list and the second one from you for returning object when there is param id also /project

Answer (score -1):

This code below solves this problem just for workaround for now

```
@GetMapping("/project")
public <Any> Any getProject(@RequestParam Optional<Integer> id) {
    if (id.isEmpty()) {
        return (Any) projectService.getProjects();
    }

    Optional<Project> project = projectService.getProject(id.get());

    if (project.isPresent()) {
        return (Any) project.get();
    }

    return null;
}
```

Comment: This shows the abuse of `Optional` as a glorified `null` check. Use it properly and do `project.orElseGet( () -> null)`; Or even better return a `ResponeEntity<Any>` and do `return ResponseEntity.of(project);`.